# MobileFirst server connect error for hybrid app on Android

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing a hybrid app with MobileFirst that uses an HTTP adapter to connect to a REST service. On my preview in firefox or any other browser there are no errors and the app runs nicely.

If I deploy the app to my Samsung Galaxy S4 mini. I get the error below and the app doesn't connect to the server.

```
klasserrorCode: "UNEXPECTED_ERROR"errorMsg: "Unexpected errorCode occurred. Please try again."invocationContext: nullresponseHeaders: Object__proto__: ObjectresponseText: ""status: 0__proto__: klassconstructor: function klass() {errorCode: nullerrorMsg: nullgetAllHeaders: function () {getHeader: function (name) {getHeaderNames: function () {initialize: function (transport, invocationContext) {invocationContext: nullresponseJSON: ""responseText: ""status: -1__proto__: Object main.js:160
```

The permissions for internet usage is set on the `AndroidManifest.xml

My adapter code (One of the functions):

```
function getCommonInformation() {
    var path = "users/common/information";

    var input = {
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType : 'json',
        path : path,
    };

    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

Call in the app of the adapter:

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/RESTAdapter/getCommonInformation", WLResourceRequest.GET);
resourceRequest.send().then(function(result) {
    dataStore.common = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
}, onFailure);
```

Comment: can you add the logcat output?

Comment: Could you show the connection code please, there may be an issue in the setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that your app is still configured to connect to `http://localhost:10080/` follow these steps to change your IP to your machine's IP/Host

- Right Click application folder inside the `apps` folder: **Right Click** > **Build Settings and Deploy Target...**
- Check **Build the application to work with a different MobileFirst server** box
- Enter your machine IP address, port number (10080), context (usually project name) `http://YOUR_MACHINE_IP:10080/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME`
- Rebuild the application

If you are using the built-in server in MobileFirst studio, make sure the your phone and MobileFirst server (your computer) are on the same network and that port 10080 is not blocked on your computer.